# Set Firefox to open links (from other applications) in a new tab?

Tags: firefox

I am trying to find a way to open hyperlinks (from app other applications on my mac such as mac mail or tweetdeck) into a new tab in FireFox V57. Currently the links are opened in the most recent active tab.

Comment: The add-on `TabMixPlus` has this option, though I have abandoned FF since the latest changes have become too restrictive. I believe that there is a release for FF Quantum under development, but I don't know when It's due. I have changed to Waterfox and Pale Moon, which both support legacy add-ons, including `TabMixPlus`.

Comment: What version of Firefox are you using?

Comment: firefox version 57.0.4